# Can you debug a python file that is called by a bash script in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have some python code that calls a bash script that calls another python file. I'm trying to debug the code in PyCharm but breakpoints in the innermost file don't seem to be getting reached.

The code is set-up is as follows:

`outter.py` *calls->* `bash_script` *calls->* `inner.py`

I put breakpoints in `inner.py` but when I try debugging `outter.py` the breakpoints in `inner.py` aren't reached. I put some print statements in `inner.py` that print to stdout so I know the file is actually getting reached.

Admittedly, it's been a hot second since I've used PyCharm so I don't quite know if I'm doing something wrong or if something weird is going on because of the bash file.

EDIT:
The specific calls are as follows:

```
#outter.py
...
subprocess.run('./bash_script param1', shell=True)
...
```

```
#bash_script
...
python3 -m inner.py "$@"
...
```

Comment: How does outter.py calls the bash_script?

Comment: subprocess.run('./bash_script param1', shell=True)

Comment: PyCharm isn't necessarily running your `inner.py` file. An independent process is being spawned which runs `inner.py`. The new process has no knowledge of your breakpoints. In a case like this, I would advise you to (while debugging), run `inner.py` through pycharm with the debugger on. If you need to set `sys.argv` yourself to "simulate" what would be there when the batch script runs it, then do that (`sys.argv[1] = param1; sys.argv[2] = param2; …`)

Comment: I was worried I would have to do that lol

Answer (score 4):

PyCharm has in fact a special support for such cases, it's called "Python Remote Debug" (which is not the obvious naming, but I created a ticket to fix that https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39230).

Here is the relevant doc page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config You can ignore "remote" part altogether.

You basically need "Python Remote Debug" run configuration, which start the debugger Java frontend in a loop waiting for a connection from a Python backend (`pydevd-pycharm`).

Install `pydevd-pycharm` on the interpreter used to run `inner.py` and add

```py
import pydevd_pycharm
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('localhost', port=12345, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

somewhere inside `inner.py` where you want to stop (adjust the port if needed). Than run `outter.py`. It will call bash, bash will call `inner.py`, `inner.py` will call `pydevd_pycharm`, `pydevd_pycharm` will establish connection to the debugger Java frontend and pause the script execution. Now switch to debugger toolwindow in PyCharm and step through your code as usual.

I created a ticket to improve docs as well https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39229 Feel free to vote/comment.

Comment: wait is the remote debug feature only in the professional version of pycharm? https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for not noting it in the answer.